# UWP app Sideloading - AppInstaller not installing the app

Tags: windows, xamarin.uwp, msix, appinstaller

I am trying to use .appinstaller to instal UWP application.
This was working fine until my laptop OS was on 1909. After we upgraded to 21H2 recently in May '22, it stopped installing and displays error :- *"App installation failed with error message: Appinstaller operation failed with error code 0x80D03002. Detail: Unknown error (0x80d03002)"*

If I run the MSIX file, it installs fine on 21H2 as well.

Already tried starting Delivery Optimization Service as suggested in [AppInstaller XML Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64381453/appinstaller-xml-issue) --- didn't seem to fix the issue.
Below is the xml code for AppInstaller:-

```
Below is the xml code for AppInstaller:-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AppInstaller
    Uri="http://XXX/TestApp.UWP.appinstaller"
    Version="2.2112.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2017/2">
    <MainBundle
        Name="TestUI"
        Version="2.2112.0.0"
        Publisher="CN=Test, OU=GIS, O=&quot;Test Corporation &quot;, L=Fremont, S=California, C=US"
        Uri="http://XXX/TestApp.UWP_2.2112.0.0_Test/TestApp.UWP_2.2112.0.0_x64.msixbundle" />
    <Dependencies>
        <Package
            Name="Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.4"
            Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
            ProcessorArchitecture="x64"
            Uri="http://XXX/TestApp.UWP_2.2112.0.0_Test/Dependencies/x64/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.4.appx"
            Version="2.42007.9001.0" />
        <Package
            Name="Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2"
            Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
            ProcessorArchitecture="x64"
            Uri="http://XXX/TestApp.UWP_2.2112.0.0_Test/Dependencies/x64/Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2.appx"
            Version="2.2.29512.0" />
        <Package
            Name="Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2"
            Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
            ProcessorArchitecture="x64"
            Uri="http://XXX/TestApp.UWP_2.2112.0.0_Test/Dependencies/x64/Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2.appx"
            Version="2.2.28604.0" />
        <Package
            Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00"
            Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
            ProcessorArchitecture="x64"
            Uri="http://XXX/TestApp.UWP_2.2112.0.0_Test/Dependencies/x64/Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.appx"
            Version="14.0.29231.0" />
    </Dependencies>
    <UpdateSettings>
        <OnLaunch
            HoursBetweenUpdateChecks="0" />
    </UpdateSettings>
</AppInstaller>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the cause. Even though it is hosted as a website AppInstaller could not access the `Uri`, so instead of using `Uri = "http://"` I used a local file path `Uri = "file://"`

Fix :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AppInstaller
    Uri="file://XXX/TestApp.UWP.appinstaller"
    Version="2.2112.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2017/2">
    <MainBundle
        Name="TestUI"
        Version="2.2112.0.0"
        Publisher="CN=Test, OU=GIS, O=&quot;Test Corporation &quot;, L=Fremont, S=California, C=US"
        Uri="file://XXX/TestApp.UWP_2.2112.0.0_Test/TestApp.UWP_2.2112.0.0_x64.msixbundle" />
    <Dependencies>
        <Package
            Name="Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.4"
            Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
            ProcessorArchitecture="x64"
            Uri="file://XXX/TestApp.UWP_2.2112.0.0_Test/Dependencies/x64/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.4.appx"
            Version="2.42007.9001.0" />
        <Package
            Name="Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2"
            Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
            ProcessorArchitecture="x64"
            Uri="file://XXX/TestApp.UWP_2.2112.0.0_Test/Dependencies/x64/Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2.appx"
            Version="2.2.29512.0" />
        <Package
            Name="Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2"
            Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
            ProcessorArchitecture="x64"
            Uri="file://XXX/TestApp.UWP_2.2112.0.0_Test/Dependencies/x64/Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2.appx"
            Version="2.2.28604.0" />
        <Package
            Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00"
            Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
            ProcessorArchitecture="x64"
            Uri="file://XXX/TestApp.UWP_2.2112.0.0_Test/Dependencies/x64/Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.appx"
            Version="14.0.29231.0" />
    </Dependencies>
    <UpdateSettings>
        <OnLaunch
            HoursBetweenUpdateChecks="0" />
    </UpdateSettings>
</AppInstaller>
```

Answer (score 0):

The appinstaller protocol has been temporarily disabled by Microsoft due to security concerns. Check out the link below for more details.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/msix/the-ms-appinstaller-protocol-has-been-disabled/m-p/3038361

Comment: This I have already taken care of in index.html. Error message is not about the protocol issue.